# Complex-sqrt function in scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to create a function that uses gamma and delta to calculate the complex square root. I have the helper functions defined already but I don't know what to do with the actual function because both gamma and delta take in two parameters and complex-sqrt has only one. Can someone please help?

[image]

```
(define (sgn b)
  (cond ((> b 1) 1)
        ((= b 0) 0)
        (else -1)))

(define (gamma a b)
  (cond ((= a 0) 0)
        ((= b 0) 0)
        (else (sqrt(/ (+ a (sqrt (+ (* a a) (* b b)))) 2)))))
(define (delta a b)
  (* (sign b) (sqrt (/ (+ (* -1 a) (sqrt (+ (* a a) (* b b)))) 2))))

(define (complex-sqrt x)
  (+ gamma delta))
```

Comment: What are the two inputs to `gamma` and `delta`? Are they the real and imaginary parts of `x`?

Comment: The point of this exercise is usually that you implement your own complex numbers using a data structure (a list or a pair or something like that), not that you write a wrapper for your Scheme's complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The two parameters to `gamma` and `delta` are the real and imaginary parts of the complex number. So you just need to split `x` into its real and imaginary parts before calling those functions.

And in the result, `gamma` returns the real part, while `delta` returns the imaginary part. So you shouldn't be adding the two results, you use them as the arguments when making a new complex number.

```
(define (complex-sqrt x)
  (let ((a (real-part x))
        (b (imag-part x)))
    (make-complex (gamma a b) (delta a b))))
```

Replace `realpart`, `imagpart`, and `make-complex` with the actual function names that you defined in the complex number implementation from that week's lab, as mentioned in the instructions.

Comment: A little confusion, what is "realpart" and "imagpart"? Are they functions that return something?

Comment: They return the real and imaginary parts of a complex number. Didn't you already define functions like that earlier in the chapter?

Comment: I don't know the actual names that were used in your textbook, you'll obviously have to replace them with whatever you called them.

Comment: The instructions refer to "the complex number implementation from this week's lab". So haven't you already done all that?

Comment: `(define (make-complex a b)
  (+ a (* b (sqrt -1))))
(define (real x)
  x)
(define (imag x)
  (* (sqrt -1) x))` This is what I have from the lab. And complex-sqrt returns 0.16641084420406216-3.004611883266907i. While the second part is correct, the beginning shouldn't be there. Any suggestion?

Comment: `real-part` and `imag-part` are built-in functions in Scheme.

Comment: Your `imag` function doesn't return the part of a complex number, it turns a real number into the corresponsing imaginary number by multiplying by `i`.

Comment: It also has a built-in function `make-rectangular` that's equivalent to `make-complex`.

Comment: See the documentation on numeric functions at https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_5.html